# Regarding taking the luggage in connection flights

Tags: air-travel

I have another question regarding taking the luggage. I cannot connect to the Qatari itself in my country maybe someone assured me. I wanted to buy a ticket online from the airline website itself which offers whole route for me. Does anybody know regarding the below photo does airline itself take my luggage to the destination or I need to do it myself in Melbourne? The flights will be changed but the website itself offers the ticket.

For europe for example I cam 2 years ago with qatari from iran to poland. but it has connection in denmark and flight changed to SAS. I did not take my luggage in denmark and just stamp passport and qatari gave it to me in poland.

However, for this option I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: Did you call Qatar Airways to check if the bag will be connected all the way or not?

Comment: [Qatar Airways](https://www.qatarairways.com/en-gb/partners-codeshare.html) offers [interline agreements](https://simpleflying.com/airline-interlining-agreements/) with many airlines including baggage transfer. I'd expect this to be the case for most journeys booked on their website, but there are sometimes obscure rules at specific airports or for specific transits (an example not relevant here is flying through Newark), so you should check to be sure (either online by checking what they say when you make the booking, or by contacting the airline).

Answer (score 1):

This page should help. While it does not list Air New Zealand as a Codeshare Partner in the Asia-Pacific section, it does mention down the bottom right that Interline Partners also enjoy:

> seamless connectivity and through-baggage check-in.

https://www.qatarairways.com/en-au/partners-codeshare.html

However, I understand that this does not specifically mention Air New Zealand. In the unlikely case that you need to re-check your bags, you would claim your bags from the baggage carousel and then take them to the transfer counter or check-in so they could process them. You would likely already have your boarding pass, either way.

The Air New Zealand website mentions that there is no way of knowing until you land in Melbourne.

> However, some countries, like the United States, still require you to pick up your bags, go through customs, and re-check them at a transfer or check-in desk. Aside from America where it's always mandatory, the only way to know for sure is to ask at the counter when you check-in at the airport.

> If your connecting journeys are separately ticketed, you will indeed need to check in separately for each one, collect your bags and re-check them in between.

Of course, it is all on one ticket, so the second part does not apply. The only way to confirm would be to call the airlines - but whatever happens, if you have to, you can check when you land in Melbourne and you should have time to do so (2 hrs 5 min).

https://www.airnewzealand.com.au/checked-in-baggage#connecting

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. They did not answer well and said that they will tell you in counter. My issue is layover time if they check the buggage then that time is less than enough I think. Anyhow, one person told me there is no check actually for this kind of flight since it is connection